# How to non-interactively set the become password in ansible-console?

Tags: ansible, console, sudo

I'm using `ansible-console` in a barebones way (no Ansible configurations (files) saved), in order to execute commands on multiple hosts.

As a requirement, the sudo (become) password for the hosts is an environment variable, say `MY_BECOME_PWD`.

Is there any non-interactive way to provide the become password to `ansible-console`, using the env variable `MY_BECOME_PWD`, even indirectly?

I've tried in different ways (it seems I should set `ansible_become_pass` or `become_pass`), but I always get the `Missing sudo password` error when I issue a command on the hosts (via `shell` console command).

Comment: --extra-vars "ansible_become_password=${MY_BECOME_PWD}" in ansible "classic", this working

Comment: There isn't such argument in `ansible-console`.